# Flutter: return int variable from future function is stateless widget : Edited and changed

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have stateless widget contain future function to get a value (not a list) from database:

```
Future<int> getUserStatus() async {
    var url =
        "http:/xxxxxx/api/controller/users/status_user.php?username=$username";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    var savedDayID = int.parse(data['d_id'].toString());
    return savedDayID;
  }
```

How can I put the value returned in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

```
final myVariable = await getUserStatus();
```

Make sure to handle the exception that int.parse() could throw.

For building UI components, have a look at the FutureBuilder.

I'd reconsider the design of trying to do url fetching inside the build method. The reason being that the build method should be possible to run many times at the will of the framework.

Comment: I tried to do that ,but inside (Widget build(BuildContext context) it isn't accept await ,and before it  it doesn't accept getUserStatus();

Comment: Well that's not the question you posed. My response actually answer your question.

Comment: I'll add a line in my response to guide you in the right direction 

Comment: thanks ,but I mentioned that I am on stateless widget

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I missed that!

Comment: I'd reconsider the design of trying to do url fetching inside the build method. The reason being that the build method should be possible to run many times at the will of the framework.

Comment: I changed it to future builder and it is succed